# HTML: Any likely scenarios where document.ready might not fire?

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

In my case I'm using dojo on IE8, but this is a general question.  What *might* be the cause of document.ready not firing?

My code looks like this:

```
require(["dojo/ready"], function (ready)
{
    alert("never gets here");
    ready(doit);
});
```

So now that I'm asking this, I see it might be an issue of "dom/ready" never loading and have nothing to do with document.ready.  Hmm...

Comment: Silly suggestion. Can you please check dojo library is loading with require in network inspector.

Comment: Good question but yes, the require method is defined and many modules load.  All of them I believe.  No scripts are failing to load.  Weird.

Comment: Use your browser Developer Tools (F12) and open the Console tab. Then refresh the page and you should see an error message.

Comment: It should work, so make sure there are no errors. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/1s43y8nt/

Comment: You would think so...you'd also think I'd see some mdi document not loading but neither of those things is the case.  All documents load and no errors are logged.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a function inside the 'ready' part. For example:

```
require(["dojo/ready"], function (ready){

ready(function(){
     alert("now I'm here");
})});
```

Comment: 'doit' is an external function.  It works on all other clients and sometimes on this client.  I'm guessing the document.ready is not firing but I supposed what I should do is hook up a document.ready callback to confirm that.

Comment: Does it also happen when you use dojo/domReady ?